# Is there a subject in this sentence?

Tags: subjects

> "kindly share how you felt when you heard
>   an announcement that a bus, plane or train you’ve been waiting for will be delayed."

Is there a subject in this sentence? thank you.

Comment: The matrix clause (the sentence as a whole) is an imperative one where the subject is not overtly stated but is understood as "you". Note that the embedded dependent clauses have overt subjects.

Answer (score 1):

Imperative sentences, in English, usually skip the subject and it is understood to be the pronoun that indicates the target of the command:

- (You) be quiet!
- (You) sit down!

Indeed, explicitly stating the subject of an imperative actually acts to intensify it, somewhat, in common English usage.